# PHP time and date setting wrong

Tags: php, date, time

I have the following code that renders a table:

```
<?php foreach ($list_acquisti as $acquisto): ?>
    <tr class="<?= ($acquisto->used == 1) ? 'muted' : '' ?>">
        <td>
            <?= $acquisto->acquisto ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= ($acquisto->paid == 1) ? $this->lang->line('profile_pagato') : $this->lang->line('profile_non_pagato') ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= $acquisto->token ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= ($acquisto->used == 1) ? $this->lang->line('profile_usato') : $this->lang->line('profile_non_usato') ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            //Problematic line
            <?= timestamp_to_date($acquisto->timestamp, $this->session->userdata('lang')) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

On the `//problematic line` I wrote a function with this:

```
function timestamp_to_date($data_orig_stamp, $lang = 'it'){
        if($lang == 'it'){
            return date('d/m/Y', $data_orig_stamp).' alle '.date('H:m', $data_orig_stamp);
        }else{
            return date('M d, Y', $data_orig_stamp).' at '.date('h:m A', $data_orig_stamp);
        }
    }
```

The weird behavior has something to do with this function:

While the MYSQL table contains this:

[image]

***Last record has a different time than the first two***

The result is this:

[image]

***Showing ALL the same time***

For some reason the ***MINUTES*** stays the same no matter what time I set in...

Does anybody know why? What's the error I am making?

***EDIT:***

This `1378801096` shows this: `10/09/2013 alle 10:09`
And this `1378801764` shows this: `10/09/2013 alle 10:09`
The same even if very different time (same date but different time)

Comment: The only logical explanation is that `$acquisto->timestamp` is an empty value.

Comment: @Jon: I'm sorry but `$acquisto->timestamp` is set as in the 1st image, and actually gets shown there. The first image I posted is actually taken from the mysql.

Comment: @DipeshParmar: `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`

Comment: The output is show, but wrong. THE MINUTES for some reasons don't seem to change.

Comment: Use `i` for minutes, __not__ `m`.... `m` is months

Comment: @MarkBaker: tks! That's the reason! (I did the script at 09 am and was showing the same as the month 09... Didn't noticed it.) TKU. Post as an answer so I can check it.

Comment: @Mr.Web: The fact that it exists in your SQL doesn't necessarily mean that it exists in your code. Use `var_dump()` to see the different variables and what they contain (including objects or arrays)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: The SQL output IS OK. The error was what MarkBaker showed. Tks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As MarkBaker suggested, the error was:

Use `i` for minutes, ***not*** `m`.... `m` is months

This handed it.